# Visual Studio and Remote Server SSH

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, remote-server

I've problems when trying to connect **VS Studio** in my *mac M1* with **remote server SSH**.

I tried it but I got this error:

```
Command 'Remote-SSH: Add New SSH Host...' resulted in an error
A system error occurred (EROFS: read-only file system, open 'ssh nhannani@192.168.110.60')...
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: what is VS Studio?

Comment: Does [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/openssh-might-fail-when-root-file-system-read-only#:~:text=To%20avoid%20this%20error%2C%20you%20need%20to%20mount,another%20file%20system%20directory%20that%20is%20mounted%20read%2Fwrite%5D.) help?

Answer (score 0):

> Command 'Remote-SSH: Add New SSH Host...' resulted in an error A
> system error occurred (EROFS: read-only file system, open 'ssh
> nhannani@192.168.110.60')...

This error message suggests that the file system on your Mac is mounted as **read-only**.

Please check if your file system is mounted as read-only by running the `mount` command in a terminal. Look for the line that corresponds to your file system, and check if it has the `ro` (**read-only**) option set.

Comment: Yes, I got /dev/disk3s1s1 on / (apfs, sealed, local, read-only, journaled)... what should I do to change it?

Comment: @NabilahHannani Can [this](https://macpaw.com/how-to/hard-drive-read-only-permission#:~:text=There%20are%20two%20possibilities%20when%20you%20see%20a,your%20user%20account%20from%20writing%20to%20the%20disk.) help?